# Is this skateboard piece LEGO?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I bought some second-hand Lego and it's a total mish-mash of parts. There was a small quantity of Mega-Bloks in it, but those parts always seem easy to identify. However, I'm stumped about this piece that resembles a skateboard, only it doesn't have wheels.  On the top, it's skateboard shaped and has two hollow studs for attaching a minifig's feet. On the bottom it has two bar-sized handles, one at each end of the skateboard. The handles are at an angle, because the skateboard flares upwards. There is a green and blue sticker on the bottom which I assume is original and not added by the previous owner.

I've searched Bricklink, Peeron, Rebrickable, and Brickset but can't find this piece. Any ideas? It's clearly Lego-compatible, if not Lego, but I have no idea what it is called.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You were on the right track. This is a skateboard, but it is not a LEGO part. It's a Mega Bloks part, probably from set 9167 (X Mountain). The skateboard in the top right has a sticker that seems to match your description.

[image: 9167 X Mountin]

The wheels clip on to allow them to pivot back and forth. I can only assume that this is to give these skateboards a more off-road feel.

Comment: That's exactly it. The sticker matches, and I recognize some of the other pieces, such as that ladder, the big green cones, and those wheels. Sadly, I threw out the wheels when I was first sorting the parts because they looked like remnants of some other toy mixed in with this lot. Oh well.

Comment: Sadly? But.. it's MEGABLOKS.  *grin*

Comment: @gev Yeah, it's megabloks, but I am still annoyed when I have an incomplete something. Anyway, MB isn't ALL bad. They have a few parts that Lego could do well to copy, and I'm sure I accidentally sorted some MB parts into my main collection. If they can fool me, then they must be good enough, right?

Comment: True enough. While my sample size is pretty small (one medium size HALO set and some random bricks elsewhere), it's pretty uniformly worse than even Kre-O and Cobi bricks. I agree that I'd love to see some of their designs copied by LEGO.